# MySQL subquery to count average of select field

Tags: mysql

I have a table called users which has details of users for example the user_id, language. I am currently selecting the fields I need to work with like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.language 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.year=2016
```

This gives me results with the user_id and the language. Is there a way to have a subquery to count the number of each language and have a column with the number of that language and have another column with the percentage of that compared to all languages. I did a little mockup below of how I would like the data to look

[image]

This is what I have tried and works but I have had to put the language in there which should be dynamic:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.language, 
((SELECT count(*) FROM users u WHERE language='English') / (SELECT count(*) 
FROM users u)) *100 AS percentage 
FROM users u
```

Comment: This looks like homework assignment. Can you share with us the effort you've done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: It's not a homework far from it LOL,I've updated my post showing what I have tried which works if I put the language in the WHERE clause, but I would like to get the language in the WHERE clause to come from the u.language in the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a derived table that contains the information you want, i.e. count per language, and join your table to it:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.language, 
       c.cnt_per_language as count,
       (c.cnt_per_language / t.total) * 100 AS percentage 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT count(*) AS cnt_per_language, language  
   FROM users 
   GROUP BY language
) AS c ON u.language = c.language
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM users) AS t
```

The derived table uses a `GROUP BY` clause in order to get the count per each language. This is the key difference between this query and the effort you made to get the result you want.

**Note:** The info about the total number of records is just a scalar value, so we can use `CROSS JOIN` to get it.